# How can a profile see a public report when sharing is off?

Tags: reporting, record-access-level

A certain profile of mine can see a public folder, that he shouldn't.

My wide setting for Enhanced Folder setting is enabled

[image]

I have a certain folder, which the users in this specific profile (custom profile) see, whats' even more funny, is that when they see the folder, and open the sharing, they don't see themselves :-)

*created testtest folder to see
* the hidden user is : system administrator. No one else has share access.

[image]

I thought that this happens because I use the Login as user feature. But not. It doesn't happen with other users from other profiles.

Only one profile seem to have the issue.

The profile settings for public folders and reports are:

These are the relevant settings (as I know) of this user profile

[image]

[image]

[image]

Any idea where do I need to start looking? how come the user has access to the report folder?

Answer (score 0):

Please see the 'Note' section of this blog post
http://simplysfdc.blogspot.co.uk/2014/09/salesforce-enhanced-folder-sharing-for.html?utm_content=buffer6cb43&utm_medium=social&utm_source=plus.google.com&utm_campaign=buffer

Comment: Can you provide more explanations please ? Giving a link is not really an answer !